# I am having infinite problems trying to install and run Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, yajl

I'm trying to install and setup Jekyll as use it for github pages but is getting very complicated, I have to add that I just started programming few months ago so maybe I cannot see the mistake as easy.

Followed the instructions on website:

```
~ $ gem install jekyll
~ $ jekyll new myblog
~ $ cd myblog
~/myblog $ jekyll serve
# => Now browse to localhost:4000
```

The part of `jekyll serve` fails:

```
Generating...   Liquid Exception: cannot load such file -- yajl/2.0/yajl i
n _posts/2014-03-21-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': c
annot load such file -- yajl/2.0/yajl (LoadError)
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
 `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0-x86-mingw32/lib
/yajl/yajl.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
 `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
 `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0-x86-mingw32/lib
/yajl.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:i
n `rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pygments.rb-0.5.4/lib/pygments/
popen.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
 `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
 `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pygments.rb-0.5.4/lib/pygments.
rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
 `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
 `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/tags/hi
ghlight.rb:52:in `render_pygments'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/tags/hi
ghlight.rb:45:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.5/lib/liquid/block.r
b:106:in `block in render_all'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.5/lib/liquid/block.r
b:93:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.5/lib/liquid/block.r
b:93:in `render_all'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.5/lib/liquid/block.r
b:82:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.5/lib/liquid/templat
e.rb:124:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.5/lib/liquid/templat
e.rb:132:in `render!'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/convert
ible.rb:88:in `render_liquid'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/convert
ible.rb:150:in `do_layout'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/post.rb
:259:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb
:239:in `block in render'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb
:238:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb
:238:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb
:39:in `process'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/command
.rb:18:in `process_site'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/command
s/build.rb:23:in `build'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/command
s/build.rb:7:in `process'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/bin/jekyll:97:in `
block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/c
ommand.rb:180:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/c
ommand.rb:180:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/c
ommand.rb:155:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/r
unner.rb:422:in `run_active_command'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/r
unner.rb:66:in `run!'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/d
elegates.rb:8:in `run!'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/i
mport.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

Googling I found out that is necesary to install `yajl-ruby gem`, I do it, try again, same error so I try installing also `gem pygments` and `win32-api` but it keeps the same.

Also I tried to uninstall the current version `1.4.3` and installed the previous one `1.4.2` but the same problem appears.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifically aiming to use Jekyll with GitHub pages you can use their gh-pages Gem, which includes all the dependencies.

Try this [install guide](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages).

Comment: I followed the instructions via bundler (the same error) and via "gem install github-pages", but when I use the command "bundle exec jekyll serve" I have the same error again.